# How to convert a JSON to java object and vice versa in spring controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a simple Spring project that will serve as a RESTful service.

I want to send JSON from frontend and want to convert it to a Java object using `@RequestBody`. After modifying the object in the backend, I need to convert that object back to JSON and send to front end.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Jackson library. An example can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

Answer (score 2):

Serialization (POJO -> JSON) and deserialization (JSON -> POJO) in Spring is simply obtained via `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` annotations.

You just need to define a Java class that represents/maps your JSON object on server-side.

Example:

#### Input JSON

```
{id: 123, name: "your name", description: ""}
```

#### Java class

```
public class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

#### Methods in your controller

```
public void postJson(@RequestBody MyClass o){
    // do something...
}

public @ResponseBody MyClass getJson(){
    // do something...
}
```

**NOTE** I omitted `@RequestMapping` settings.

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the jars required for this?

Comment: dont we need jackson jars??if requirede what are those?

Comment: Can anyone share a small demo app with the required jats inside it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide csrf token for POST request. Instead you can try this.

[sending HashMap by angularjs $http.get in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060493/sending-hashmap-by-angularjs-http-get-in-spring-mvc)

It works fine just a bit extra @RequestParams but on the better side you can send additional information too and not only the respective object.